# URxvt not pulling from .Xresources when starting X. Issue with .xinitrc?

Tags: bash, arch-linux, terminal, rxvt, dwm

I have my DWM Archbox configured to launch a URXVT terminal when X is started. I have URXVT configured just how I like through my .Xresources file. Below is my .xinitrc

```
#! /bin/sh

exec xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources &
exec dwm &
exec ~/.fehbg &
exec urxvt
```

When X starts, the wallpaper through .fehbg appears fine but the terminal doesn't have any of the .Xresources settings (to include appearance and perl scripts) with the weird exception of the font (loading Inconsolata)

If I open another terminal, the .Xresources settings load fine and I get my desired terminal look and functionality.

Anyone know what the issue may be?

**Update:** After getting rid of all the execs except for the last one (moved dwm to last) I still had the same issue. I added `sleep 1` after loading the wallpaper and URXVT finally loaded correctly. Curious as to why this worked.

Answer (score 1):

## Do not put multiple exec’s!

From [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xinit#xinitrc):

> Remember that lines following a command using exec would be ignored. For example, to start xscreensaver in the background and then start openbox, use the following:
>
> > ~/.xinitrc
> >
> > ...
> >
> > xscreensaver &
> >
> > exec openbox-session

I actually don’t know why your setup works for wallpaper, but I’m pretty sure that if you remove all the `exec`s it will be better. Also put the `exec dwm` on the last line as it is the main program managing everything else

This is how your `.xinitrc` should look like:

```bash
xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources &
~/.fehbg &
urxvt &

exec dwm
```

**Edit:** got it, you do not need to launch `xrdb` in background (using ampersand `&`), because otherwise `urxvt` might open *before* previous tasks are completed (that's the whole point of background processes I guess)

So either you remove the `urxvt` from your `.xinitrc`, or you make the `xrdb` run in foreground before it, which is not really something bad in this case as it normally takes only a moment to complete so you should not feel any difference (except properly working terminal)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I took a look at the wiki and fixed my .xinitrc as you suggested. Unfortunately that didn't fix the problem. Still getting wallpaper but no Xresources other than the prescribed font.

Comment: Should be OK now, check the edit. Somehow forgot about this